# Cant Get Broadcasting to work in C

Tags: c, sockets, broadcast, broadcasting

I used the [broadcaster.c](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/broadcaster.c) from [Beej's Guide to Network Programing](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#broadcast) as well as the [listner.c](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#datagram) but am unable to make have a Broadcast packet send to the server. I have checked in Wireshark and it does send. But I cannot get the listener to receive the connection. It only seems to work for localhost and 192.168.1.56 and not for 255.255.255.255 or 192.168.1.255.

Comment: I forgot to put a rule in my firewall

Answer (score 1):

If you bound the socket to the `broadcast address` (either manually or `INADDR_BROADCAST`) or `INADDR_ANY` on the server part, then it would receive the broadcast, otherwise Linux will not receive the packets.

Btw, routers do not forward `255.255.255.255` broadcast. Therefore, don't use it on the infrastracture mode.